# Two colors in one text field using Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to have two text colors in one text field using Actionscript 3.0?

ex: how can i make like the first string black and the second string red?

Here is my code when using a single color:

```
    public function logs(txt)
    {
        if (txt == '')
        {
            textLog.text = "Let's Open up our treasure boxes !!!";
        }
        else
        {
            textLog.text = '' + txt + '';
        }
        textLog.x = 38.60;
        textLog.y = 60.45;
        textLog.width = 354.50;
        textLog.height = 31.35;
        textLog.selectable = false;
        textLog.border = false;
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var myFont:Font = new Font1();
        format.color = 0x000000;
        format.font = myFont.fontName;
        format.size = 18;
        format.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        format.bold = false;
        textLog.embedFonts = true;
        textLog.setTextFormat(format);
        this.addChild(textLog);
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `setTextFormat` you can specify start index and end index.  You can also render text as html using `textLog.htmlText`.

First set the text

```
var t:TextField  = new TextField();
t.text = "BLUEGREEN";
addChild(t);
```

Then method 1

```
var format1:TextFormat = t.getTextFormat(0, 4);
format1.color = 0x0000ff;
t.setTextFormat(format1, 0, 4);


var format2:TextFormat = t.getTextFormat(5, t.length);
format2.color = 0x00ff00;
t.setTextFormat(format2, 5, t.length);
```

Or method 2

```
t.htmlText = '<font color="#0000ff">BLUE</font><font color="#00ff00">GREEN</font>';
```

Comment: how can i do that bro ?  would you like to give an example ?

Comment: I have modified the answer with sample. Please check. Remember that you need to apply format after setting text.

Comment: Please use `.length` property of string to set indexes if you don't want to hard code.

Comment: thanks @Diode, but the problem is the text is dynamic, according to the string that not defined, like you found : blah.... or you found the 100 coins, some time not all text is two color, it just one color, in any case it not all the time have the two color, and not all them have the same length, could you like to explain how can i do such as problem ?, i have edited the question, thanks again Diode

Comment: Thats why I asked to use `.length` property of string. Here in the example instead of (0, 4) you have to use `(0, firstString.length)`.

Comment: If you are using second method you can create string like this.
`t.htmlText = '<font color="#0000ff">' + firstString + '</font><font color="#00ff00">' + secondString + '</font>';`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do like that, you need create a function to control. charAt(DEFINE INDEX OF STRING HERE).

```
    var format2:TextFormat = textbox.defaultTextFormat;
    format2.color = 0x000000;
    textbox.defaultTextFormat = format2;

    if((textbox.text.charAt(3) == "d") && ( textbox.text.charAt(4) == "i")){            
        var format1:TextFormat = textbox.defaultTextFormat;
        format1.color = 0xFF0000;
        textbox.setTextFormat(format1, 3, 5);}
    else{
        textbox.setTextFormat(textbox.defaultTextFormat);}
```